# How is the type information saved after casting in the generic class?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-erasure

```
class FixedSizeStack<T> {
  // ...
  private Object[] storage;
  // ...
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
  public T pop() { return (T)storage[--index]; }
}

public class Program {
  // ...
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FixedSizeStack<String> strings = new FixedSizeStack<String>;
    // ... filling an array
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      String s = strings.pop();
      System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

**Eckel** (*Thinking in Java*) in his book says that `pop()` method doesn't actually do any casting, `T` is erased to `Object` and `pop()` is actually just casting an `Object` to an `Object`. OK, but how is the information about String objects saved, if `String` is erased to `Object` and method returns `Object`? In this case the compiler has to say something about incompatible types. Why does this code work?

Comment: Generics are gone after compiling. It just ensures object compatibility at compile time. And as your `FixedSizeStack` has the generic `String` everything is fine

Comment: Compile and runtime are different. The type information is there at compile time, but erased at runtime.

Comment: The compiler erases the _whole lot_ and creates [bridge methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html) for generic _input_ parameters. Generic _output_ parameters are cast at point of use - so, in your example, `String s = (String) strings.pop()`. I would suggest you read the rest of the linked tutorial...

Comment: Strings _are_ objects and although you don't specifically define it you can read it as `String extends Object` (with some intermediate classes). Hence you can store strings in an `Object` array and cast them to `Object`.